# Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

I am getting runtime error while running the following code on leetcode.
When I am removing the user-defined comparator function it is working fine. But with user define comparator function it is giving runtime error as follows :

> Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of
> type 'int' (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:
> undefined-behavior
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:9

```
class Solution {
private:
    static bool comp (vector<int> p1, vector<int> p2) {
        if(p1[0] < p2[0] || p1[1] < p2[1])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
public:
    int maxEnvelopes(vector<vector<int>>& envelopes) {
        if (envelopes.empty())
            return 0;
        sort(envelopes.begin(), envelopes.end(), comp);
        vector<int> dp(envelopes.size(), 1);
        int res = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < envelopes.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i-1; j >=0; j--) {
                if (envelopes[j][0] < envelopes[i][0] && envelopes[j][1] < envelopes[i][1] && dp[j] + 1 > dp[i])
                    dp[i] = 1 + dp[j];
            }
            res = max(res, dp[i]);
        }
        
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: I ended up back here after upvoting the answer 363 days ago!

Comment: Aaand I'm here again (facepalm)

Answer (score 16):

It's a classic mistake. Consider this pair of vectors

p1 = {1, 4} and p2 = {2, 3}

Now comp(p1, p2) is true because 1 < 2 but  comp(p2, p1) is also true because 3 < 4. So how is sorting supposed to work when p1 is less than p2 **and** p2 is less than p1?

You need to write a comparison function that makes sense. Perhaps something like this

```
static bool comp (vector<int> p1, vector<int> p2) {
    return p1[0] < p2[0] || (p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] < p2[1]);
}
```

Comment: How is your answer targeting the runtime error? I get the logical error in the OPs question, but your answer doesn't tackle the undefined behavior found by the sanitizer.

Comment: @RaduC Because of the logical flaw the behaviour of the OP's code is undefined. Undefined behaviour can manifest itself in many ways, I don't know why this particular case result in that particular error. I imagine that somehow or other an empty vector is being passed to the comparison routine, but only close examination of the sorting code would say for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The actual sanitizer error is not about the logic of the comparator. It actually triggers when a vector is empty and you try to dereference an element in that vector.
You checked that `envelopes` is not empty, but further down you went ahead and used `envelopes[i][0]` without checking that `envelopes[i]` actually has any elements.

Comment: Although the other answers help to fix future bugs, this is the only one addressing the question, which is the runtime error (and is the answer I was looking for)

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the answer given by @john, your comparison function needs to follow a *strict-weak-order*.

A layman's explanation is your comparison functions states that `a` comes before `b` in the ordering, but at the same time `b` comes before `a` in the ordering.  That is a violation of the strict-weak-order, and thus the `std::sort` gets confused and goes into undefined-behavior land.

The answer given by @john should work, however there is a simple, almost foolproof way of doing the comparison.  The simple way of comparing multiple items, where the comparison will cascade down from one item to the next, is to use [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

For example you want to compare `a`, `b`, of two items, where if the `a` values are equal, then compare the `b` values (in your case, the `a` value is `p1[0]` and `p2[0]`, and the `b` values are `p1[1]` and `p2[1]`:

```
static bool comp (const vector<int>& p1, const vector<int>& p2) {
    return std::tie(p1[0], p1[1]) < std::tie(p2[0], p2[1]);
}
```

This will automatically compare `p1[0]` to `p2[0]`, and if they are equal `p1[1]` to `p2[1]`.  If you had more items to compare, you just specify them in the `std::tie` calls.